# Need inner div to overlap outer div (both need transparency)

Tags: html, css

I could really use your help.

I have an inner div which needs to extend past an outer div...that part isn't a problem. My issue is, I need help making the outer div clip where the inner div is extending. Problem is, they both need to be transparent.

Please see the below image to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

[inner and outer div image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwemD.jpg)

Here is what I have so far:

CSS:

```
.infoBoxOuter {
  border: 10px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}
.infoBoxInner {
  width: 350px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="infoBoxOuter">
  <div class="infoBoxInner">
    <h1 class="white">Lorem Ipsum dolor</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need transparency, I think you are basically looking at one of two possibilities:

1. Use an SVG for the border shape with the cutout on the side
2. Generate the top, left, and bottom borders one way or another (most easily with a border on `.infoBoxOuter`) and then use a pseudo element or two to create the right side with the gap.

Below is an example of approach #2. You could either do the top-right line as one pseudo element and the bottom-right line as another one, or you can do what I've done below and use a gradient to go between white and transparent.

You can adjust the numbers as needed for your situation. I just tried to get something roughly similar to your example image to get you an idea of how this works.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, midnightblue, steelblue);
}
.infoBoxOuter {
  color: white;
  border-top: 10px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 10px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.infoBoxOuter::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, white 25px, transparent 25px, transparent 140px, white 140px, white);
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.infoBoxInner {
  width: 350px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="infoBoxOuter">
  <div class="infoBoxInner">
    <h1 class="white">Lorem Ipsum dolor</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```